# JQuery stop toggle at class

Tags: jquery, click, toggle

I currently have div classes for filters that cannot be changed.  I want to have a .toggle so when one section is clicked the rest are hidden up to the next class ".refinement_custom_category_section".  Currently it is almost working, it just hides EVERYTHING below the section, when I only want to hide that one section when clicked.

```
  <div class="refinement_custom_category_section">Find by Condition</div>
  <div class="refinement_filter"><a href="">New (52)</a></div>
  <div class="refinement_filter"><a href="">Used (7)</a></div>
  <div class="refinement_filter"><a href="">Overstock - New (2)</a></div>
  <div class="refinement_custom_category_section">Find by Section</div>
  <div class="refinement_filter"><a href="">1 Section (2)</a></div>
  <div class="refinement_filter"><a href="">2 Section (40)</a></div>
  <div class="refinement_filter"><a href="">3 Section (19)</a></div>
  <div class="refinement_custom_category_section">Find by Door Type</div>
  <div class="refinement_filter"><a href="">Solid Door (34)</a></div>
  <div class="refinement_filter"><a href="">Glass Door, Sliding (6)</a></div>
  <div class="refinement_filter"><a href="">Glass Door, Swing (21)</a></div>
  <div class="refinement_custom_category_section">Find by Exterior</div>
  <div class="refinement_filter"><a href="">Black (33)</a></div>
  <div class="refinement_filter"><a href="">Stainless Steel (28)</a></div>
  <div class="refinement_custom_category_section">Find by Height</div>
  <div class="refinement_filter"><a href="">34.5 inches (12)</a></div>
  <div class="refinement_filter"><a href="">35.625 inches (16)</a></div>
  <div class="refinement_filter"><a href="">35.875 inches (11)</a></div>
  <div class="refinement_filter"><a href="">37 inches (20)</a></div>
  <div class="refinement_filter"><a href="">38.75 inches (2)</a></div>
</div>
<script>
$(".refinement_custom_category_section").click(function () {
$(this).nextAll("div.refinement_filter").toggle("fast");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/):

```
$(this).nextUntil("div.refinement_custom_category_section").toggle("fast");
```

`nextAll` will select *all* siblings that match the selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".refinement_custom_category_section").click(function () {
  var $subcat = $(this).nextUntil("div.refinement_custom_category_section");
  $(this).siblings("div.refinement_filter").not($subcat).hide();
  $subcat.toggle();
});
```

Comment: That would hide everything but the elements selected in `$subcat`. This is not what the OP wants: *when one section is clicked the rest are hidden **up to** the next class ".refinement_custom_category_section"*